# Which preposition should be used, in or during?

Tags: prepositions

> Take care of your health **during/in** weather changes.

Which preposition should be used before 'weather changes'?

Answer (score 1):

A change is a point in time, abstractly speaking, hence *when the weather changes* would be correct.

In sounds odd to me, whereas "during" signals a continuous distance in time and thus requires the present progressive "Be taking care during ...". Although, in "your health during weather changes" it's not focused on the verb, you'd imply the consequences of the weather for health would be limited to times during weather changes, which isn't wrong either.