# Which preposition would be correct: "in" or "during" a time period?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

In the sentence below, which preposition is the correct one – *in* or *during*? Or are they both correct? In that case, is there a difference in meaning?

*Following an expansive phase in/during 2020, we will now slow down production.*

Comment: Prepositions are ***very*** flexible in English. For example, the sequence *will **slow up** production* is [almost as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+slow+up+production%2Cwill+slow+down+production&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) as *will **slow down** production*. So don't worry about the choice between ***in*** and ***during*** - at least those two (equally valid) options are near-synonymous, which you certainly can't say about ***up*** and ***down*** in many other contexts!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which preposition should be used, in or during?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121935/which-preposition-should-be-used-in-or-during)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you! Both your comments are very helpful!

Comment: You can often think of ***during*** as a slightly more "emphatic" alternative to ***in*** when applied to "some period of time". That's because plain ***in*** can carry many other senses (you can be ***in** a football team*, or ***in** love*, for example). But ***during*** ONLY works for a "period of time" (or "event that happens non-instantaneously"), so arguably it inherently draws attention to that ***within some duration*** aspect.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think your comments make a better answer than your suggested duplicate, which suggests that "in" is awkward here, which it's not. I'd certainly upvote an answer comprised of your two comments.

Comment: @RyanM: You're quite right. I looked at several other related earlier questions, but I guess my eventual choice was just "the best of a bad bunch" for this exact question. So I've gone the extra mile, and retracted my closevote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepositions are often *very* flexible in English. For example, the sequence *will slow **up** production* is [a perfectly valid and common alternative](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20slow%20up%20production%2Cwill%20slow%20down%20production&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) to *will slow **down** production*...

[image]

So don't worry about the choice between ***in*** and ***during*** here. At least those two (equally valid) alternatives are near-synonymous, which you certainly can't say about ***up*** and ***down*** in many other contexts!

You can often think of ***during*** as a slightly more "emphatic" alternative to ***in*** when we're referencing "some period of time" (such as *the year 2020* here). That's because plain ***in*** can carry many other senses (you can be ***in** a football team*, or ***in** love*, for example).

But ***during*** ONLY works for a "period of time" (or "event that happens non-instantaneously"), so arguably it inherently draws attention to that *"**within** some **duration**"* aspect - rather than *"**at** that [point in] **time**"*.

Comment: The graph would make more sense if it was about the problem presented, i.e. “during 2020”/“in 2020”

Comment: That's not the purpose of the chart, So far as I'm concerned, I've *entirely* addressed the OP's specific question in my final two paragraphs above - and that's not to mention the bracketed aside *(**equally valid**)* as mentioned before that, which should be quite enough for such a trivial question. The point of the chart is to drive home my main message - ***Prepositions are often very flexible in English***. With a contextually relevant example, given that OP's text does in fact include ***slow down*** as opposed to the equally valid ***slow up***.