# When to use "To + verb-ing"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

We use "To + verb" and "verb-ing" but I don't understand the where **to verb-ing** is correct to use. For instance:

> 1. I am addicted "to playing" games.
> 2. When it comes "to running", no one can beat him.
> 3. My reaction "to seeing" you cry like a baby....
> 4. What is the secret "to living" happily.

Are the sentences correct even with the *to* in front of the *verb-ing*?
Could you explain the syntax and when to use such structures?

Comment: These are all correct. They would make no sense without the "to".I will leave it to someone else to provide a careful explanation of the the grammar.

Comment: There's no particular reason to link the PREPOSITION ***to*** with your example gerunds / continuous participle verb forms. In all your examples, the ***-ing*** word is just the first word in a multi-word NOUN PHRASE (except #2, where the gerund ***running*** is a noun all on its own). The preposition simply provides the necesaary "syntactic glue" to join together the rest of the words in each sentence.

Comment: [*Prepositions are **very** flexible in English.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/271011/which-preposition-would-be-correct-in-or-during-a-time-period#comment505312_271011) For example, you could use ***upon*** instead of ***to*** in #3 (or ***for, of,...*** in example #4).

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the phrase structured differently, with the "to" associated with the word coming before it, you may understand better what is happening:

(I am) (addicted to) (playing games).

When (it comes to) (running), no one can beat him.

My (reaction to) seeing (you cry) (like a baby)....

(What is) (the secret to) (living happily)?

then you see that the "to" is not actually dependent upon the verb, but to the thing that comes before it.

Comment: +1 I would only add that, in case it's not obvious from what you've said, the "to" would still be there if a noun were substituted for the -ing word.  "My reaction to the sight of you crying...", "What is the secret to a happy life?", "When it comes to a race, no one can beat him", etc.  This shows how important it to understand that this structure is not comparable to that of a "to"-infinitive.